# gnu parallel pipe sed - no input files error

Tags: unix, sed, replace, find, gnu-parallel

I am using the following `sed` script to perform some find and replace:

```
parallel --pipepart --block 1000M -a input.txt sed -ise 's/cat/dog/g; s/abc/xyz/g; s/def/22/g' > output.txt
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
sed: no input files
```

I tried removing the `-i` option but the outcome is still the same.

input.txt file contains a combination of alphabets and numbers and contains around 30 million lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `-q`:

```
parallel -q --pipepart --block 1000M -a input.txt sed -se 's/cat/dog/g; s/abc/xyz/g; s/def/22/g' > output.txt
```

To understand why:

- https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#QUOTING
- https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_design.html#Always-running-commands-in-a-shell

Also `--block -1 --lb` may be more efficient than `--block 1000M`.

Comment: using the options `-q` and `--lb` did the trick. Thank you @Ole Tange !!